# Trigger file download from an email link

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, email, download

I have generated an email that contains a link from which a user should click and download a file. 
The message variable "$message" contains my attempt of achieving this by having an href linking to the file location.

```
    function senddivorceGuide() { 
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] =="senddivorceGuide") {
        $details = $_POST['info'];
        $name = $details[0];
        $to = trim($details[1]) ;

        $subject = "Divorce Guide";
        $message = $name ."<h1> Thank you for your Interest on our Guide
    , click on the         link below to download it.</h1><br><a 
      href=\"http://www_site_co_uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/file.pdf/\">Click here to download the guide</a> ";          
        $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html";           
        wp_mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);           
        $headers = "Content-type: text/plain";

 }
```

}

How can that download be automatically triggered when the user clicks the link?
Thank you all in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `can that download be automatically triggered when the user clicks the link`? Are you asking if file can set to download without any confirmation from the user?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just link to the PDF document in the message string? If the PDF file is hosted in a web-accessible location, then clicking on a link to it will launch the user's browser and immediately open the file.